# Using curl and Oauth2 client_credentials with Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure, curl, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get an access token from Microsoft's Azure AD Graph API using curl, but I keep getting a 400 Bad Request.

Here is the command I'm running:

```
curl -v --data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<my id>&client_secret=<my secrect>"  https://login.windows.net/<my app guid>/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
```

The response I get is:

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"ACS90004: The request is not properly formatted.\r\nTrace ID: 095ca93a-744c-41b1-b531-0db5b8ec9e07\r\nCorrelation ID: 46eb70ad-6053-498a-8fd5-6ee7b52d5e72\r\nTimestamp: 2013-11-07 17:51:15Z","error_codes":[90004],"timestamp":"2013-11-07 17:51:15Z","trace_id":"095ca93a-744c-41b1-b531-0db5b8ec9e07","correlation_id":"46eb70ad-6053-498a-8fd5-6ee7b52d5e72"}

Comment: Removing the "?api-version=1.0" from the URL got me past this issue and I'm now onto another...

Comment: Encode the Request Body and try once more..